# Why APIs of WSO2 APIManager can not be called successfully?

Tags: api, wso2

I want to test API of APIManager, I use the tool soapUI to call the interface listAllUsers of UserAdmin service through the endpoint 
`https://host:8243/services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint`, and I also added admin user/password in basic authentication header. But I can not get the result.

the error message output in APIManager console as following.

```
    [2014-03-01 16:52:11,296] ERROR - AuthenticationHandler
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invalidateSession(AuthenticationHandler.java:215)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:175)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,300] ERROR - AxisEngine Authentication failure
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,302] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for
: /services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpointorg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Authentication failure
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:123)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,352]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-03-01 16:52:11,351+0800]
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,356] ERROR - Class System failure.null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.doAuthorization(AuthorizationHandler.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,359] ERROR - AxisEngine System failure.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System failure.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
[2014-03-01 16:52:11,361] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for
: /services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: System failure.
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthorizationHandler.invoke(AuthorizationHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

According to the error message, it seems like admin user/password is not correct,
But When I call the same API of DSS as the same method, it is OK!

I do not know why.

Comment: It is working by me. Did you enable the admin webservice? as documented in http://charithaka.blogspot.nl/2013/06/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

Comment: Thank you.But I think the reason is the port incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the ports to Servlet ports. Then the port should be 9443 not 8243.

```
https://host:9443/services/UserAdmin.UserAdminHttpsSoap11Endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

Port change solves the problem. It is still suggested port in the wsdl as 8243 but actually it should be 9443